# How to bind events and properties of controls in UniformGrid dynamically?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

I am a newbie in templating Wpf controls. I use VS2013, WPF 4.5 and **Caliburn Micro 2.0.2**. In part of tasks I have I need to populate a grid with toggle buttons contained different images and its subtitle. I have solved it using UniformGrid. See my code below. They work but still don't have event and property binding since I don't know how I can bind the events and properties of toggle buttons to view model, since they are generated automatically and dynamically and the number of toggle buttons is uncertain (depends on the number of images in the image folder).

For example:
**manually** I could bind the Click event, IsChecked property and some other properties of toggle button 1 like following:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleVehicle01" IsChecked={Binding SelectedVehicle01} Background="{Binding BackColorSelectedVehicle01}" ToolTip="{Binding VehicleName01}">
```

But **now I can't do that anymore** since the toggle buttons are generated automatically and their number is uncertain. Please help. **Feel free to change my code below** or give me examples code that works. Thank you in advance.

The View (MainView.xaml):

```
<UserControl x:Class="CMWpf02.Views.MainView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         d:DesignHeight="300"
         d:DesignWidth="300"
         mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid Width="1024"
          Height="768"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          ShowGridLines="True">
        <ItemsControl Name="ImageList"
                      Background="#FFFFFFFF"
                      BorderBrush="#FFA90606"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=VehicleImages}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ToggleButton Width="180"
                                  Margin="10,10,10,10"
                                  FontSize="10"
                                  Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ToggleButtonStyleKey}}">
                        <!--  x:Name="ToggleVehicle01"  -->
                        <!--  Background="{Binding BackColorSelectedVehicle01}"  -->
                        <!--  IsChecked="{Binding SelectedVehicle01}"  -->
                        <!--  ToolTip="{Binding Vehicle01Name}">  -->
                        <StackPanel Margin="0,5,0,5"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <Image Width="140"
                                   RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant"
                                   Source="{Binding Path=Image}" />
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       FontWeight="Bold"
                                       Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ToggleButton>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The ViewModel (MainViewModel.cs):

```
using Caliburn.Micro;
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IO;

namespace CMWpf02.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel : Screen, IHaveDisplayName
    {
        private String _path2Images = @"D:\tmp\Images";
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<VehicleImage> VehicleImages { get; set; }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            DisplayName = "Main Window";
            var vehicles = new ObservableCollection<String>();
            vehicles = GetAllFilesFromFolder(_path2Images);
            VehicleImages = new ObservableCollection<VehicleImage>();
            foreach (var i in vehicles)
                VehicleImages.Add(new VehicleImage(i));
        }

        public ObservableCollection<String> GetAllFilesFromFolder(String fullPathFolder)
        {
            string[] fileArray = Directory.GetFiles(fullPathFolder);
            return new ObservableCollection<String>(fileArray);
        }
    }

    public class VehicleImage
    {
        public String Image { get; private set; }
        public String Name { get; private set; }

        public VehicleImage(String image)
        {
            Image = image;
            Name = Path.GetFileName(image);
        }
    }
    //public void ToggleVehicle01()
    //{
    //    var selectText = (SelectedVehicle01) ? " selected" : " unselected";
    //    MessageBox.Show(Vehicle01Name + selectText);
    //    BackColorSelectedVehicle01 = (SelectedVehicle01) ? _backColorSelectedVehicle : _defaultBackColorVehicle;
    //}

    //public Boolean SelectedVehicle02
    //{
    //    get { return _selectedVehicle02; }
    //    set
    //    {
    //        _selectedVehicle02 = value;
    //        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedVehicle02);
    //    }
    //}

    //public Brush BackColorSelectedVehicle02
    //{
    //    get { return _backColorSelectedVehicle02; }
    //    set
    //    {
    //        _backColorSelectedVehicle02 = value;
    //        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => BackColorSelectedVehicle02);
    //    }
    //public String Vehicle01Name { get; private set; }
}
```

**EDIT:** Now I can bind the properties of generated ToggleButton with view model. I make the VehicleImage class to a view model (see modified code below). But I still have **problem to bind Click-event of generated ToggleButton** to view model.

The **modified** class to view model

```
public class VehicleImage : PropertyChangedBase
{
    public String Image { get; private set; }
    public String Name { get; private set; }

    private Boolean _selectedVehicle;
    public Boolean SelectedVehicle
    {
        get { return _selectedVehicle; }
        set
        {
            _selectedVehicle = value;
            BackColorSelectedVehicle = _selectedVehicle ? new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 242, 103, 33)) : new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        }
    }

    private Brush _backColorSelectedVehicle;
    public Brush BackColorSelectedVehicle
    {
        get { return _backColorSelectedVehicle; }
        set
        {
            _backColorSelectedVehicle = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => BackColorSelectedVehicle);
        }
    }

    // ToggleButton's Click-Event Handler, but it doesn't get event trigger from View.
    // Therefore I set the BackColorSelectedVehicle fin setter of SelectedVehicle property.
    public void ToggleSelection()
    {
        //BackColorSelectedVehicle = SelectedVehicle ? new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 242, 103, 33)) : new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    }

    public VehicleImage(String image)
    {
        Image = image;
        Name = Path.GetFileName(image);
    }
}
```

The **modified** view

```
<ToggleButton Width="180"
              Margin="10,10,10,10"
              Background="{Binding Path=BackColorSelectedVehicle}"
              FontSize="10"
              IsChecked="{Binding Path=SelectedVehicle}"
              Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ToggleButtonStyleKey}}"
              ToolTip="{Binding Path=Name}">
              <!--  x:Name="ToggleSelection"  -->
    <StackPanel Margin="0,5,0,5"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Image Width="140"
               RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant"
               Source="{Binding Path=Image}" />
               <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
    </StackPanel>
</ToggleButton>
```

Comment: What do you want these property/event bindings to do?  The MVVM way would be to add properties like `IsChecked` to `VehicleImage` (or a `VehicleImageViewModel`).

Comment: I know how the MVVM Caliburn Micro way for binding in common. eg. <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleVehicle01"/> in View will be bound wth public void ToggleVehicle01() in ViewModel (I have added the commented-out code in the view model). In templated automatically generated ToggleButton I can't give x:name to ToggleButton because the number of ToggleButtons is uncertain. Therefore I want to know how to bind events and properties in such automatically generated control.